# Facebook Issue on Authentications

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an error on my facebook page which throws

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Cannot query users by their username (naitik) thrown in /../base_facebook.php on line 1325
```

I have downloaded and using their github examples here

```
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk
```

I have also looked at lint too and this is the error I get

> Object Missing a Required Value   Object at URL
>   'http://dmoain.com/facebookapp/index.php' of type 'website' is invalid
>   because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not
>   provided.

What OG title I have to have there? I have these OG titles on my header but nothing changes when I comment them

```
<meta property="fb:app_id"     content="1434123820171184" /> 
<meta property="og:type"       content="product" /> 
<meta property="og:url"        content="Put your own URL to the object here" /> 
<meta property="og:title"      content="Sample Product" /> 
<meta property="og:image"      content="" />
```

Thank you

Comment: What does your code look like that throws that error?

Comment: the code was same as what Facebook has on their Github account, all I did was changing App ID and Secret, this is done now, I had to go back to previous versions to make it work. Thanks